# How can spring MVC controller ation bind to multiple models on an ajax request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The post request to my controller action is coming from ajax like this:

```
$.post("myurl.htm", { view: $("#selView").val(), 
    val1: "value1", val2: "value2"
});
```

I have two Models `Foo` and `Bar`

```
public class Foo {
   public String val1;
   //getter/setters
}

public class Bar {
   public String val2;
   //getters/setters
}
```

Now, my controller action looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myurl.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doSomething (
    @RequestParam(value="view", required=true) String view, 
    @RequestParam(value="val1", required=false) String val1, 
    @RequestParam(value="val2", required=false) String val2) {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  Bar bar = new Bar();
  if (view.equalsIgnoreCase("something"))  
     foo.setVal1(val1);
  else if (view.equalsIgnoreCase("somethingelse"))  
     foo.setVal2(val2);

  fooService.doSomeStuffWithDb(foo);
  barService.doSomeStuffWithDb(bar);

}
```

**Questions**

1. Even though, everything above works I think there should be a better way to do this...? What if I had 10 parameteres posting in my post request, would I have 10 parameters in my controller action?? This would not scale well.
2. So, is there a way that spring can automagically bind the parameters to there relevant getters/setters on the model?

Comment: see if this helps http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?64923-Does-Spring-MVC-not-handle-binding-request-params-to-model

Comment: @SubinS The url u given is different then what questioner has demanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring can inject request parameters as a Map:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doSomething (@RequestParam Model<String, String> params) {
    params.get("val1");
    params.get("val2");
    // ...
}
```

use your javascript unmodified. this is not as elegant as the `@ModelAttribute` version, but scales prety well with a lot of parameters.

Comment: hmmm I'm trying the first approach you suggested but getting a `400` error. `Bad request`. I'll ensure everything again

Comment: sorry, i mixed up RequestParam and ModelAttribute... please try again

Comment: `@ModelAttribute` doesn't throw `400` error however the values are not binding to the model. Please note that I'm not using `RequestMethod.GET` at all in my case. The parameters are just being posted via ajax. I'll review my side of things again as well

Comment: even `req.getQueryString()` inside the controller isn't outputting anything, which is an issue. Thanks for your help. I'll take another look...

Comment: @Omnipresent hmm, my code depends on RequestMethod.GET... but i have a third suggestion :)

Comment: ok great, I thought I was crazy. Because everywhere I looked, it suggested that Binding and ModelRequest depend on the `GET` request since that passes the model to the view. Your third suggestion will have to do for now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing many variables to the controller, its best to start to use an object to hold these params.  This object is sometimes known as a data transfer object (DTO).

Here is an example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public String create(@Valid Market market, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "markets/create";
    }

    // store market

    return "redirect:/markets/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(market.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
}
```